# Compare lists in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, comparison, fact

I need to compare a list to a fact which includes a list. For example I have two facts:

```
level1(toothed_whale,[1,2]).
level1(baleen_whale,[2,1]).
```

I want to create a predicate which compares these facts with list of my creation. If I compare `level1` with the list `[1,2]` I want the function to return `toothed_whale`. If I compare level1 with the list `[2,1]` it should return `baleen_whale`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but you can just execute simple queries.

For instance:

```
2 ?- level1(X,[1,2]).
X = toothed_whale .

3 ?- level1(X,[2,1]).
X = baleen_whale.
```

Is this what you're asking?

Comment: No not really. I want to compare the facts with other lists. For example if I were to compare level1 with a list [1,1] it should return false.

Comment: if you execute `level(X,[1,1]).` you would get false.

Comment: can you add it to your question? It's hard to see it this way

Comment: Sorry. Anyway I completely solved it now. It was really simple(just did as you said). Thanks again :)

Comment: @user3651900 if this answered your question or solved your problem, make sure you accept this as an answer.